# How to explain ID card format in text?

Tags: text, formatting

In an iOS app I have a identity card field. I want to show users the format. What the most appropriate/clear to describe the following regex:

```
[XYZ]{1}[0-9]{7}[TRWAGMYFPDXBNJZSQVHLCKET]{1}
```

Currently I have:

```
Starting with 1 letter (X, Y, or Z), followed by 7 digits (0-9),
and ending with 1 letter (A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, J, K, L, M,
N, P, Q, R, S, T, V, W, X, Y, or Z); without any other character
or space.
```

Considerations:

- How to indicate ranges of digits/letters, is `(0..9)` or `(0 - 9)` better?
- Should I write `(A-H, J-N, P-T, or V-Z)` (should I use `or` here actually?) instead, or perhaps `(A-Z except I, O or U)`?
- Should I write `7 digits` or `seven digits`, ...
- ...

What's best in a situations like this?

Comment: Is the user creating their ID here or are they inputting an ID that they already have?

Comment: @DasBeasto They are entering an existing ID, for example of their national identity card. Interesting question, what are you thinking about?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the digit range is not restricted (0-9) you may omit this information, this strips some complication off the sentence. What about:

```
X, Y or Z, followed by 7 digits, followed by any letter except I, O or U.
```

If any other rule is violated (for example spaces or special characters have been added) you could display a more specific error message.

Comment: How nice! Seems I've too hard been trying to translate the regex.